# Panel with percentage coordinates

Tags: wpf, animation, resize, panel, coordinates

I would like use a panel whose children have coordinates specified as percentage of total panel's width/height. Moreover, I should be able to animate the coordinate property, for example to make a button move from 10% to 50% panel's width.

I've made 2 attempts:

1. Use a Grid and specify size as stars - this was not enough, because AFAIK by default WPF cannot animate distance properties specified by stars. I've found somewhere a custom class that enabled me to do so, it even worked, hovewer I consider that solution overly complicated an I am looking for something simpler.
2. Use a Canvas with fixed width and height and put it inside a Viewbox - this is a simple solution, but when resizing the Viewbox the whole content of Canvas is resized too. I want the content to have fixed size.

Is there a simple solution or should I implement my own panel (or maybe extend one of the existing ones, i.e. Canvas)?

Cheers!

Comment: Use Canvas without Viewbox. Content will have a fixed size then u can calculate the % of it in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would:

- subclass `Canvas`, perhaps calling it `RelativeCanvas` or `RatioCanvas`
- add two attached properties: `XRatio` and `YRatio`
- override `ArrangeOverride` and loop over all children. For each child, use their `XRatio` and `YRatio` along with the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the `RelativeCanvas` to calculate and apply values for their `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties

You would use it as follows:

```
<local:RelativeCanvas>
    <!-- the top-left of this button will be center of panel -->
    <Button local:RelativeCanvas.XRatio="50" local:RelativeCanvas.YRatio="50"/>
</local:RelativeCanvas>
```

One thing you might like to add after you get that working is control over alignment. For example, I might to align the *center* of a control to the specified ratio, not its top-left corner.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the ArrangeOverride method, this seems to be the cleanest solution. I'll put the new panel in some dll making it reusable.

Comment: can you explain in some detail? How to calculate new left and top based on XRatio and YRatio? How to get XRatio and Yratio?

Comment: Note, the steps above are *not enough* if you were to ever bind `XRatio`/`YRatio` (even to const value). Even though the `Canvas.Top` is set correctly during `ArrangeOverride()`, it is *not respected* for data-bound values (perhaps some internal ordering issue?). Only XAML literals seems to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

There's one here: [WPF Proportional Panel](http://alecbryte.com/post/2009/01/16/WPF-Proportional-Panel.aspx)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: the link is still dead